# Retrieve Only Modified Files After Visual Studio Publish (NB : More of a knowledge gathering)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

First of all, i'am not looking for a code sample. I just want some directions on something am working on. I'am an intermediate C# developer and i'am developing something, something like a pet/side project [huh.., it's just a crappy form application :-)].

Currently am working on a ASP.NET MVC Web project. When our client request for a change, we make the change and publish the project, then we we copy only the modified/newly added files(.cshtml, .css, .js etc..) and bin files(.dll) (if there is any controller, model etc change during the development) and replace/add them to the server.

What i'am trying to achieve is, after publishing i run a form app and it list all the projects in TFS, then i can select a project and select any changeset associated with the project(usually the latest one or two changesets) and upon click next it finds the modified/newly created files (.cshtml, .css, .js etc..) and modified(modified on the day of publish) bin files(.dll) and copy to desktop in the same folder structure as publish folder as a single compressed file, it is kind of like automating the 'picking apples (or) files'.

I have almost completed the above however just to know is there any tools for this already available that i'am not aware of or is there some option in VS to perform this? Am just a developer and didn't know the endless possibilities of VS (which i'am excited each day while learning it..)

Also please note i don't want to publish all my files to server directly from VS which i'am already aware of.

[EDIT]
I know simply i can create a batch file to find modified files in a folder and do the needed (my rocket engineering solution above vs simply doing it..!! ). I just want to know is there something already in VS etc...

Comment: Personally I think it is best to push all the files in a deploy.  If you need to know which files were modified I would look in the history for the project and check the changesets

Comment: @ken, Thank you for your time. Currently we connect to server via RDP and manually copy the files. So deploying all files takes some time because of the size. "If you need to know which files were modified I would look in the history for the project and check the changesets" :- currently iam doing it via programatically to achieve this. I jsut wanna know is there some other way to do this. :-)